# Using requests to PUT <key,value> into etcd results in empty value

Tags: python, python-requests, etcd

I'm trying to use requests to run a simple PUT and add a new  pair to etcd (which I have running locally). I am able to do this just fine by directly calling etcd like so:

```
curl -X PUT http://127.0.0.1:2379/v2/keys/message -d value="Test Message"
```

However, the code below, which I thought would be equivalent to that, doesn't seem to work:

```
import requests
r = requests.put('http://127.0.0.1:2379/v2/keys/message', data = 'value=\"Test Message\"')
print(r.content)
```

The print statement above shows me this:

```
b'{"action":"create","node":{"key":"/message/35","value":"","modifiedIndex":35,"createdIndex":35}}\n'
```

So it appears that the value of *value* is empty for some reason. I've tried various formats for the *data* parameter but didn't have any luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you can get the sent request from `r` by `r.request`. And then you can see what's wrong with it:

```
>>> r = requests.put("http://www.example.com", data="value=\"Test Message\"")
>>> r.request
<PreparedRequest [PUT]>
>>> r.request.url
'http://www.example.com/'
>>> r.request.body
'value="Test Message"'
>>> r.request.headers
{'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.18.4', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 'Accept': '*/*', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Content-Length': '20'}
```

Second, I think you should use `r = requests.put('http://127.0.0.1:2379/v2/keys/message', data={"value": "Test Message"})`

Comment: Can you update your answer if I am using python 3.8.14 and etcd 0.12? It doesn't work for me...@sraw